# Cloudera Impala Queries failing

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

I am trying to get Impala set up on our cluster but when I try to select count(*) from our table I get the following error.

```
Query: select count(*) from events
ERROR: AnalysisException: Failed to load metadata for table: events
CAUSED BY: TableLoadingException: Failed to load metadata for table: events
CAUSED BY: MetaException: javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Fetch of object "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MTable@3faf7a03" using statement "SELECT `A0`.`DB_ID`,`B0`.`DESC`,`B0`.`DB_LOCATION_URI`,`B0`.`NAME`,`B0`.`DB_ID`,`A0`.`SD_ID`,`C0`.`INPUT_FORMAT`,`C0`.`IS_COMPRESSED`,`C0`.`IS_STOREDASSUBDIRECTORIES`,`C0`.`LOCATION`,`C0`.`NUM_BUCKETS`,`C0`.`OUTPUT_FORMAT`,`C0`.`SD_ID`,`A0`.`VIEW_EXPANDED_TEXT`,`A0`.`VIEW_ORIGINAL_TEXT` FROM `TBLS` `A0` LEFT OUTER JOIN `DBS` `B0` ON `A0`.`DB_ID` = `B0`.`DB_ID` LEFT OUTER JOIN `SDS` `C0` ON `A0`.`SD_ID` = `C0`.`SD_ID` WHERE `A0`.`TBL_ID` = ?" failed : Unknown column 'C0.IS_STOREDASSUBDIRECTORIES' in 'field list'
NestedThrowables:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'C0.IS_STOREDASSUBDIRECTORIES' in 'field list'
CAUSED BY: JDODataStoreException: Fetch of object "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MTable@3faf7a03" using statement "SELECT `A0`.`DB_ID`,`B0`.`DESC`,`B0`.`DB_LOCATION_URI`,`B0`.`NAME`,`B0`.`DB_ID`,`A0`.`SD_ID`,`C0`.`INPUT_FORMAT`,`C0`.`IS_COMPRESSED`,`C0`.`IS_STOREDASSUBDIRECTORIES`,`C0`.`LOCATION`,`C0`.`NUM_BUCKETS`,`C0`.`OUTPUT_FORMAT`,`C0`.`SD_ID`,`A0`.`VIEW_EXPANDED_TEXT`,`A0`.`VIEW_ORIGINAL_TEXT` FROM `TBLS` `A0` LEFT OUTER JOIN `DBS` `B0` ON `A0`.`DB_ID` = `B0`.`DB_ID` LEFT OUTER JOIN `SDS` `C0` ON `A0`.`SD_ID` = `C0`.`SD_ID` WHERE `A0`.`TBL_ID` = ?" failed : Unknown column 'C0.IS_STOREDASSUBDIRECTORIES' in 'field list'
CAUSED BY: MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'C0.IS_STOREDASSUBDIRECTORIES' in 'field list'
```

show tables works fine.

I'm using hive 0.9.0 and Impala 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a restart of the Impala service in Cloudera Manager fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could also run the `refresh` command to refresh the catalog from the impala-shell.